# Why is scrolling to top not working html?

Tags: html, backbone.js

I have a html which is a table with left & right side. on left side chapter names exist an on right all chapter content exists . when i click on a chapter on left i wish to see that chapter on top . Hence i wrote code like this

```
_clickOnChapterTopic:function(obj){
                var aid  = obj.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
                var id_rhp = aid+"_rhpend"; // this is id at end of each prev chapter 
                var classTag = '.'+id_rhp;
                this.$(classTag).scrollTop(0);
            }
```

Scroll top (0) is not working . When i printed it its always 0 .

PLeas suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to replace

```
this.$(classTag).scrollTop(0);
```

with

```
this.$(classTag).scrollIntoView()
```

Alternatively,

```
this.$(classTag).scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)
```

may better fit your needs.

Comment: The html page has many elements . It's like I want only this class div to come to top . How will window scroll move to right div to 0

Comment: Editited the answer, try now

Comment: Ethan ,  can you guide on another backbone issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404904/scroll-event-not-fired-for-backbone